# Binary Analysis Research Tools

Tags: security, binary, static-analysis

Can some one provide me with a list of leading binary research tools for Windows OS and windows applications? I found BinScope from microsoft itself but was wondering if there are any other better tools around?

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have access to the binary your access is limited.    If you want to peer into the inner workings of this binary your best bet is a Decompiler like [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) and a assembler level debugger like [OllyDBG](http://www.ollydbg.de/).

Answer (score 2):

Tom Reps, a professor at the University of Wisconsin and founder of GrammaTech, gave an impressive talk on this at Stanford last summer.  GrammaTech is working on binary analysis (http://www.grammatech.com/research/contracts/HSARPA/HSARPA-2005-MCSB/), but I don't know whether it's available in their static analysis product yet.
Disclaimer:  One of their VP's bought me lunch and got me to try a demo of their source code analysis tool while I was at Palm (before the binary analysis talk), but I think the results are confidential.

Answer (score 1):

[BAP](http://bap.ece.cmu.edu/) is a toolkit for performing binary analysis on x86 programs.  It lifts binary code to an easily understandable and analyzable language similar to compiler intermediate languages.  It's not a point and click solution (i.e., programming is required to use it effectively), but it can be useful for people who want to write new program analyses on binary code without redefining the semantics of x86.